# Tag Helpers intellisense is not working, Razor Language Services stuck in Disabled

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm having problems enabling `Razor Language Services`, which is responsible for displaying `asp-` tag helpers.

I try to switch it on, restart VS, and nothing happens.

There are no errors in error list.

Tried disabling `Razor Tools` through `.csproj` file.

Tried unloading the project.

Installed `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools –Pre`

Nothing seems to help. Any advice guys?

Answer (score 1):

I have used Razor Language Services: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d2ded120-c2ba-40b1-99cb-07e28c9269d3/view/Reviews